How to avoid having to re-enter SSH passphrase after suspend
Running KDE Plasma 5.27.11 on ubuntu 24.04.1 (LTS).  When I ssh in somewhere, a dialog pops up, into which I type my SSH passphrase.  It works, and I don't need to enter the passphrase again to connect via ssh unless I've suspended the machine.
How can I avoid having to re-enter my passphrase after suspending (suspending to RAM, AKA sleeping, not hibernating)?  Why would KDE not retain this info while suspended?  I haven't added the passphrase to my keychain because this doesn't seem like it should be necessary for my usage patterns.
